# How would you say "x is exhausting/tiring"?

Tags: translation, adjectives

I know that "I'm tired" translates to

> 疲{つか}れました

But how would you say, for example "PE class is exhausting" ?  疲れる is intransitive, so you can't say something like "PE class exhausts me", and there doesn't seem to be an adjective that has a meaning that is similar to "exhausting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to say it would be to use the pattern 「Xでへとへとです/になる」, meaning "X exhausts me."

体{たい}育{いく}の授{じゅ}業{ぎょう}でへとへとです/になる。

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this sentence, what is the function of the で particle ? How does it work in this case ?

Comment: in this case で functions as "by means of X"

Comment: There are some other verbs you can use with へとへと too, like 疲れる and する.

Comment: @Blavius へとへとに疲れる is okay but we don't say へとへとする, do we?

Comment: @Chocolate No, but へとへと**に**する works, I think.

Comment: @TFlo83 「Xでへとへとです」って言うと、"X is tiring/exhausting" じゃなくて "I'm tired/exhausted from X now"「今、Xでへとへとの状態だ/疲れている状態だ」って意味だと思うんですけど・・・

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that, in a perhaps surprising display of semantic flexibility, 疲れる can be used in a sense comparable to "tiring" or "exhausting". (Though I stop well short of calling 疲れる used in this way an adjective.) So you can say:

> 体育の授業は疲れます。(PE class is exhausting.)

Two of bona fide adjectives you may also consider in this situation are しんどい and きつい.

Comment: I see. Because it makes no sense for PE classs to *be* exhausted, you can use 疲れる in this type of situation. I didn't know Japanese was that flexible.

Comment: これはいわゆる「コンニャク文」の一種ですね。

Comment: @broccoli forest ！何やら初めて聞く興味深い用語！早速調べてみます！